# Jquery google maps transport calculator no longer working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

have Google Maps changed the way it allows scripts to access it ?. The reason I ask is I have a couple of websites with transport calculators that use jquery and json to calculate a distance between post codes using google maps.

The problem can be seen here :

http://www.sos-motorcycle-recovery.co.uk/

Under the section "get and instant quote", if you enter a couple of postcodes, lets say PE219PX and then in end journey NG323RJ , usually this would return a total distance and cost, but it doesn't do anything, and this has happened on another site too that uses the same script, which makes me wonder if Google have changed something ?. The problem is I am seeing no errors, so im not even sure where to start.

The code that runs it all looks like this :

```
    <div class="key4-module-inner">
      <div class="module-content"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=AIzaSyDfnkRoxyEYmXSgY_Dne74TaBAfglq5Lxk"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    var prefix = '/en';

    var map;
    var gdir1;
    var gdir2;
    var gdir3;
    var geocoder = null;
    var addressMarker;
    var inside_of_m25 = 0;
    var sevendaydelivery = 0;
    var gd_ready_1 = false;
    var gd_ready_2 = false;
    var do_additional_calculation = true;
    var interval_id = 0;

    var start_point = "NG32 3RJ";

    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {      
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(48.9225, 5.5371), 4);
        }
    }

    function estimate() {
            if ( $('#collection_post_code').val() == '' || $('#delivery_post_code').val() == '' ) {
            alert( "Please input a post code" );
            return;
        }

        map.clearOverlays();

        if ( GBrowserIsCompatible() && do_additional_calculation ) {

            gdir1 = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
            GEvent.addListener(gdir1, "addoverlay", onGDirectionsLoad1);
            GEvent.addListener(gdir1, "error", handleErrors1);

            setDirections( gdir1, start_point,
                            $('#collection_post_code').val(), 
                            null, null, null, null, "en_US" );

            gdir2 = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
            GEvent.addListener(gdir2, "addoverlay", onGDirectionsLoad2);
            GEvent.addListener(gdir2, "error", handleErrors2);

            setDirections( gdir2, $('#delivery_post_code').val(),
                            start_point, null, null, null, null, "en_US" );
        }

        inside_of_m25 = $('#inside_of_m25:checked').val();
        sevendaydelivery = $('#sevendaydelivery:checked').val();

        switch_tab( 'temp_block' );

        interval_id = setInterval( "finish_estimation()", 100 );
    }

    function switch_tab( tab ) {

        $('#estimator_form').hide();
        $('#content').hide();
        $('#deliverycostwrapper').hide();
        $('#temp_block').hide();
        $('#sms_email_send_status').hide();
        $('.module-title').hide();

        $( '#' + tab ).show();
    }

    function setDirections( direction, 
                            fromAddress, 
                            toAddress, 
                            nextAddress1, 
                            nextAddress2, 
                            nextAddress3, 
                            nextAddress4, 
                            locale ) {

        var query = "from: " + fromAddress;

        if ( nextAddress1 != null && nextAddress1 != "" ) {
            query += ' to: ' + nextAddress1;
        }
        if ( nextAddress2 != null && nextAddress2 != "" ) {
            query += ' to: ' + nextAddress2;
        }
        if ( nextAddress3 != null && nextAddress3 != "" ) {
            query += ' to: ' + nextAddress3;
        }
        if ( nextAddress4 != null && nextAddress4 != "" ) {
            query += ' to: ' + nextAddress4;
        }
        query += " to: " + toAddress;

        direction.load( query, { "locale": locale } );
    }

    function handleErrors(direction, dir_num) {
        if (direction.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS)
            alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for one of the specified addresses. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.\n Error code:  " + direction.getStatus().code + " [" + dir_num + "]");
        else if (direction.getStatus().code == G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR)
            alert("A geocoding or directions request could not be successfully processed, yet the exact reason for the failure is not known.\n Error code: " + direction.getStatus().code + " [" + dir_num + "]");
        else if (direction.getStatus().code == G_GEO_MISSING_QUERY)
            alert("The HTTP q parameter was either missing or had no value. For geocoder requests, this means that an empty address was specified as input. For directions requests, this means that no query was specified in the input.\n Error code: " + direction.getStatus().code + " [" + dir_num + "]");
        else if (direction.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_KEY)
            alert("The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given. \n Error code: " + direction.getStatus().code + " [" + dir_num + "]");
        else if (direction.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_REQUEST)
            alert("A directions request could not be successfully parsed.\n Error code: " + direction.getStatus().code + " [" + dir_num + "]");
        else alert("An unknown error occurred." + " [" + dir_num + "]");

        clear_map();

        show_view_form();
    }

    function handleErrors1() {
        handleErrors(gdir1, 1);
    }

    function handleErrors2() {
        handleErrors(gdir2, 2);
    }

    function handleErrors3() {
        handleErrors(gdir3, 3);
    }

    function show_view_form( clear ) {

        if ( clear ) {
            clear_estimator_form();
            clear_map();
        }

        switch_tab( 'estimator_form' );
    }

    function clear_map() {
        map.clearOverlays();
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(48.9225, 5.5371), 4); 
    }

    function clear_estimator_form() {

        $('#multiple_legs').attr('checked', '');
        $('#collection_post_code').val('');
        $('#next_post_code_1').val('');
        $('#next_post_code_2').val('');
        $('#next_post_code_3').val('');
        $('#delivery_post_code').val('');
        $('#inside_of_m25').attr('checked', '');
        $('#sevendaydelivery').attr('checked', '');

        multiple_legs_change(); 
    }

    function onGDirectionsLoad(direction, weight, show_results) {
        var poly = direction.getPolyline();
        var baseUrl = "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?";

        var params = [];
        var markersArray = [];
        markersArray.push(poly.getVertex(0).toUrlValue(5) + ",greena");
        markersArray.push(poly.getVertex(poly.getVertexCount()-1).toUrlValue(5) + ",greenb");
        params.push("markers=" + markersArray.join("|"));

        var polyParams = "rgba:0x0000FF80,weight:" + weight + "|";
        var polyLatLngs = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < poly.getVertexCount(); j++) {
            polyLatLngs.push(poly.getVertex(j).lat().toFixed(5) + "," + poly.getVertex(j).lng().toFixed(5));
        }

        if ( show_results ) {

            var distance1 = '0&nbsp;mi';
            var distance2 = '0&nbsp;mi';

            if ( do_additional_calculation ) {
                distance1 = gdir1.getDistance().html;
                distance2 = gdir2.getDistance().html;
            }

            $.post( 'return.php', 
                    { distance1: distance1,
                            distance2: distance2,
                            sevendaydelivery: sevendaydelivery,
                            distance3: gdir3.getDistance().html,
                            inside_of_m25: inside_of_m25 }, 
                    function(data) {
                        var deliverycost = (data);
                        simpleCart({
            // Set Delivery Cost
            shippingFlatRate: deliverycost });
                        $('#estimator_result_form').html( '' );
                        $('#estimator_result_form').append( data );
    $('#container').show();
                        switch_tab( 'estimator_result_form' );
                    } );

            inside_of_m25 = 0;
        }
    }

    function onGDirectionsLoad1() {
        onGDirectionsLoad( gdir1, 0, false );
        gd_ready_1 = true;
    }

    function onGDirectionsLoad2() {
        onGDirectionsLoad( gdir2, 0, false );
        gd_ready_2 = true;
    }

    function onGDirectionsLoad3() {
        onGDirectionsLoad( gdir3, 5, true );
    }

    function finish_estimation() {

        if ( ( do_additional_calculation && gd_ready_1 && gd_ready_2 ) || !do_additional_calculation ) {

            map.clearOverlays();

            gdir3 = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
            GEvent.addListener(gdir3, "addoverlay", onGDirectionsLoad3);
            GEvent.addListener(gdir3, "error", handleErrors3);

            setDirections( gdir3, $('#collection_post_code').val(), 
                            $('#delivery_post_code').val(), 
                            $('#next_post_code_1').val(), 
                            $('#next_post_code_2').val(),
                            $('#next_post_code_3').val(),
                            $('#next_post_code_4').val(), 
                            "en_US" );

            gd_ready_1 = false;
            gd_ready_2 = false;

            clearInterval( interval_id );
        }
    }

    function multiple_legs_change() {       
        if ( $('#multiple_legs:checked').val() == 1 ) {
            $('.multi_legs_option_1').show();
        } else {
            $('#next_post_code_1').val('');
            $('#next_post_code_2').val('');
            $('#next_post_code_3').val('');
            $('#next_post_code_4').val('');     

            $('.multi_legs_option_1').hide();
            $('.multi_legs_option_2').hide();
            $('.multi_legs_option_3').hide();
            $('.multi_legs_option_4').hide();
        }
    };

    function delivery_post_code_change() {
         $('#collection_post_code_2').val( $('#delivery_post_code').val() );
    }

    function send_message() {
        if ( $('#phone_number').val() == '' && $('#email_address').val() == '' ) {
            alert( "Please input phone number or email address" );
            return;
        }

        var sms_sent = false;
        var email_sent = false;

        $('#sms_email_send_status').html( '' );
        switch_tab( 'temp_block' );

        if ( $('#phone_number').val() != '' ) {
            $.post( 'return.php', 
                    { phone: $('#phone_number').val(),
                        collection_post_code: $('#collection_post_code').val(),
                        delivery_post_code: $('#delivery_post_code').val(),
                        next_post_code_1: $('#next_post_code_1').val(),
                        next_post_code_2: $('#next_post_code_2').val(),
                        next_post_code_3: $('#next_post_code_3').val(),
                        total_distance: $('#total_distance').html(),
                        total_cost: $('#total_cost').html() }, 
                    function(data) {
                        sms_sent = true;
                        result = $.evalJSON( data );
                        if ( result.success == 1 ) {
                            $('#sms_email_send_status').prepend( 'SMS has been sent!<br />' );
                        } else {
                            $('#sms_email_send_status').prepend( '<span style="color: red;">' + result.message + '</span><br />' );
                        }

                        if ( $('#email_address').val() != '' ) {
                            if ( email_sent ) {
                                show_sms_email_send_status();
                            }
                        } else {
                            show_sms_email_send_status();
                        }

                    } );        
        }

        if ( $('#email_address').val() != '' ) {
            $.post( 'return.php', 
                    { email: $('#email_address').val(),
                        phone: $('#phone_number').val(),
                        collection_post_code: $('#collection_post_code').val(),
                        delivery_post_code: $('#delivery_post_code').val(),
                        next_post_code_1: $('#next_post_code_1').val(),
                        next_post_code_2: $('#next_post_code_2').val(),
                        next_post_code_3: $('#next_post_code_3').val(),                 
                        total_distance: $('#total_distance').html(),
                        total_cost: $('#total_cost').html() 
                                            }, 
                    function(data) {
                        email_sent = true;
                        result = $.evalJSON( data );
                        if ( result.success == 1 ) {
                            $('#sms_email_send_status').prepend( 'Email has been sent!<br />' );
                        } else {
                            $('#sms_email_send_status').prepend( '<span style="color: red;">' + result.message + '</span><br />' );
                        }

                        if ( $('#phone_number').val() != '' ) {
                            if ( sms_sent ) {
                                show_sms_email_send_status();
                            }
                        } else {
                            show_sms_email_send_status();
                        }
                    } );
        }
    }

    function show_sms_email_send_status() {
        $('#sms_email_send_status').append( '<br /><input type="button" value="Start Again" onclick="show_view_form( true );" />' );
        switch_tab( 'sms_email_send_status' );  
    }

    function onEnter(event) {
        if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
            estimate();
        }
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#container').hide();
         $('#collection_post_code').keyup(function () {
             $('#delivery_post_code').val($(this).val());
              });  });
```

EDIT >>

I have just looked on the google API v2 site and it says:

Warning: Version 2 of the Google Maps JavaScript API is no longer available. Please follow the guide to migrate your code to version 3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. As of November 19, 2013, all applications requesting v2 are served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API to work for most simple maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate to the v3 API immediately.

Im now scratching my head as im not sure how on earth to convert it to API v3

Comment: What happens when you put breakpoints in and follow what happens after you make the calls to Google?

Comment: How do you put in breakpoints with chrome console ?

Comment: Click sources, Ctrl-O, open a file and then click on a line number. Alternatively type `debugger;` in your code to add one programatically.

Comment: adding debugger; just seems to open the developer tools on the line where debugger is, but doesnt actually show any info about what has been retrieved etc ?.

Comment: Yeah. Like I said, it adds a breakpoint. Your job is to sort through the data at that point. There are plenty of tutorials on the dev tools if you've not used it before.

Comment: I gave up on this plan and found this in the end which I can actually understand which is all good ! http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getdistance-55